# CS1503 C# Argument 1 : cannot convert from 'System.Reflection.Assembly' to 'System.Type'

Tags: c#

I try to make a discord bot but i get this error:

> CS1503 C# Argument 1 : cannot convert from 'System.Reflection.Assembly' to 'System.Type'.

I want to create a discord bot but because of this error I can't run it.

[image: Here is photo of my visual studio]

My Code :

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Discord;
using Discord.Commands;
using Discord.WebSocket;

namespace Risk
{
    class Program
    {
        private DiscordSocketClient Client;
        private CommandService Commands;

        static void Main(string[] args)
            => new Program().MainAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();

        private async Task MainAsync()
        {
            Client = new DiscordSocketClient(new DiscordSocketConfig
            {
                LogLevel = LogSeverity.Debug
            });


            Commands = new CommandService(new CommandServiceConfig
            {
                CaseSensitiveCommands = true,
                DefaultRunMode = RunMode.Async,
                LogLevel = LogSeverity.Debug
            });

            Client.MessageReceived += Client_MessageReceived;
            await Commands.AddModuleAsync(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly());

            Client.Ready += Client_Ready;
            Client.Log += Client_Log;

            string Token = "";
            using (var Stream = new FileStream((Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location)).Replace(@"bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.0", @"Data\Token.txt"), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            using (var ReadToken = new StreamReader(Stream))
            {
                Token = ReadToken.ReadToEnd();
            }

            await Client.LoginAsync(TokenType.Bot, Token);
            await Client.StartAsync();

            await Task.Delay(-1);
        }

        private async Task Client_Log(LogMessage arg)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now} at (Message.Source)] (Message.Message)");
        }

        private async Task Client_Ready()
        {
            await Client.SetGameAsync("Risk Bot...", "", StreamType.NotStreaming);
        }

        private async Task Client_MessageReceived(SocketMessage arg)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are passing an `Assembly` object when a `Type` is expected.

Comment: I want the correct code , someone can edit my code and correct it? I dont know what's the problem and i tried everything

Comment: Just googling that `AddModuleAsync` method I came across this https://discord.foxbot.me/docs/api/Discord.Commands.CommandService.html. Looks like it takes a `Type` object. There is another method on that page called `AddModulesAsync` (plural) that takes an `Assembly` object, which is what `Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()` returns. Is that what you need?

Comment: PROBLEM FIXED! THX FOR HELP

Answer (score 1):

Why would you pass an `Assembly` when you have a `Type` expected?
Just rename `AddModuleAsync` to `AddModulesAsync` and it should work.
Sorry, I don't have the source code to make sure it actually works but it should.